# Why should the trace of a 3d rotation matrix have these properties?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations, trace, orthogonal-matrices

On the Wikipedia article about Rotation Matrices (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Determining_the_angle), the article states that the trace of the matrix will be equal to 1 + 2 cos(theta), where the theta represents the angle of the rotation in axis/angle form.

How is this property found?  There doesn't appear to be any derivation on the site, and I can't see any reason why it might be the case.

Comment: I assume you are working with 3-d rotations?  You should specify that in the question.

Comment: Yes just 3d sorry.

Answer (score 5):

$3$D rotation is defined as fixing a pole and rotating the orthogonal sub space to that pole (a unit vector). For instance, if our pole is the vector $(0,0,1)$, we rotate the orthogonal subspace given by the $x-y$ plane.

The sub space is roared according the the rotational matrix.

Defined by:

$$\begin{bmatrix}\cos (\theta) &-\sin (\theta) \\\sin (\theta) & \cos (\theta) \end{bmatrix}$$ .

Choosing basis suitably, we can make $v_1$ our first basis vector and this is fixed by the rotation. While the other bases will be transformed according to our rotation angle. Therefore, all rotation matrices are similar to:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&\cos(\theta)&-\sin(\theta)\\
0&\sin(\theta)&\cos(\theta)\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Similar matrices have same trace so it follows.

Edit:
I should have a book somewhere explaining this in detail, if you want, let me know so that I can find the book and post an image.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to fix it.

Comment: Looks much better now. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer.  It makes plenty of sense to me that the traces would match if they were similar.  It took me a bit of convincing, but I think I can see how all rotation matrices must be similar as well, which solves my problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The 3d rotation matrix is built from multiplication between 3 rotation matrices. I understand that the same proof still holds. What can I infer from the theta that comes from the 3d rotation matrix on each one of the axes? Is the same proof still valid?

Answer (score 1):

Note that when we say that $R$ is a rotation matrix, we're really saying that there exists an orthonormal basis $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ such that

1. $R v_3 = v_3$ (i.e. $v_3$ is the "axis of rotation")
2. $R$ rotates vectors in the plane spanned by $v_1,v_2$.

So for instance, in the case that $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are the standard basis (that is, $\hat i, \hat j, \hat k$), $R$ is the matrix of the rotation in the $xy$-plane, namely
$$
R_{\theta} = \pmatrix{\cos \theta & -\sin \theta & 0\\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1}.
$$
When $v_1,v_2,v_3$ is taken to be an arbitrary orthonormal basis, the resulting matrix is
$$
R = VR_{\theta}V^{-1}
$$
where $R_{\theta}$ is the matrix above and $V$ is the matrix whose columns are $v_1,v_2,v_3$ (in other words, the change-of-basis matrix). Note: because $V$ has orthonormal columns, $V^{-1} = V^T$.

Now, it turns out that for any matrix $A$ and any invertible $S$, we have
$$
\operatorname{trace}(SAS^{-1}) = \operatorname{trace}(A).
$$
In more abstract terms, the trace of the matrix associated with a linear transformation will always be the same, regardless of the basis chosen. So, our new rotation $VR_{\theta}V^{-1}$ has the same trace as $R_{\theta}$, the "standard" rotation by $\theta$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The 3d rotation matrix is built from multiplication between 3 rotation matrices. I understand that the same proof still holds. What can I infer from the theta that comes from the 3d rotation matrix on each one of the axes? Is the same proof still valid?

Comment: @TripleS First, note that the matrix $V$ from my answer is not necessarily a rotation matrix itself; it will be if and only if $v_1,v_2,v_3$ form a right hand coordinate system. Second, I don’t understand what you’re asking. What is it exactly that you’re trying to infer? If you “understand that the same proof holds”, why are you asking if “the same proof is still valid”?